# Vesa Mode in Turbo C++

Tags: turbo-c++

How to implement vesa mode in Turbo C++?

Comment: Woah! A question somehow broke through from the Dark Ages of the Internet! Has the mule train got through with your daylight yet?

Comment: Curious as to what you are doing?  If you can - let us know?  Its been ages since Ive had to do that.  I used to play around with a game library called Allegro back in the day (with DJGPP and not Turbo C++) - maybe look that up and you might find some assembler code to get that right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this back in the day:  You need to implement the data structures and functions as determined [here](http://www.petesqbsite.com/sections/tutorials/tuts/vbe3.pdf).

A lot of `reg.h.al` and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Turbo C++ shipped with the Borland Graphics Interface (BGI), which only did up to 16-color VGA, and even then, it was anything but fast.

I think you had to roll your own or buy someone else's library to get VESA 256 color high resolution graphics working.  Keep in mind, it's been like 15 years for me...

Answer (score 0):

You buy Phar Lap DOS extender. It comes with Vesa mode drivers which you can then use in DPMI/DOS 16-bits.

If I remember correctly, the PharLap tools came with mini graphics library which you could use. It was mainly for scientific purposes... but people used to to makes instead.

Some games, like Transport Tycoon/DOS uses this method.